jam.py how to find the last item of a field and compute a running sum?
I am new with JAM.py and I am trying to create a maintenance database for aircraft.
On the form used to enter the data, I am entering the tachymeter time in (tach_in, beginning of the flight), and out (tach_out, end of the flight).
The computation of the flight duration is easy. Some pictures of the current state:
frontend form
variable names
I am struggling with the following:
a) Each time I am creating a new entry using the form, how can I automatically populate the new tach_in as equal to the previous (or last) tack_out? For example:
Flight N-2 tach_in = 100 tach_out = 101
FLight N-1 tach_in = 101 tach_out = 102

Flight N is the flight I am currently entering using the form: I would like to have the new tach_in = 102 (ie: the value of the previous/last tach_out, and I only have to enter the NEW tach_out)
Any idea on how to do that?
b) How can I perform a running sum of the flight time, to show the new total time (flight_total) after each entry?
Flight N-2 tach_in = 100 tach_out = 101 flight_duration = 1 flight_total = 1
FLight N-1 tach_in = 101 tach_out = 102 flight_duration = 1 flight_total = 2
Flight N   tach_in = 102 tach_out = 103 flight_duration = 1 flight_total = 3

Thank you for your help!

a) You need to take the last record.
Add this into your form (jam.py v7):
function on_edit_form_shown(item) {
    if (item.is_new()) {
        let copy = item.copy();
            copy.open();
            if (copy.rec_count === 0) {
                item.tach_in.value = 1 ;

            }   else {
                    let copy = task.flight.copy();
                    copy.open({fields: ['tach_out']});
                    copy.last();
                    // console.log(copy.tach_out.value);
                    item.tach_in.value = copy.tach_out.value;

            }
    }    
    if (item.tach_out.value) {
        item.flight_total.value = item.tach_out.value - item.tach_in.value;
    } else {
        item.flight_total.value = 0; 
    }
}

This can be seen on https://msaccess.pythonanywhere.com/ if for example you clone the record it will increase last Entry Number by 1.
b) Not sure that I follow. Summary is created automatically, like on above app. If Flight total is needed on the Form (like on the image), than just calculate it with JS as per above code.
This does not include changing tach values on the form, for that we need function on_field_changed to change the flight_total:
function on_field_changed(field, lookup_item) {
    var item = field.owner;
    if (field.field_name === 'tach_out' || field.field_name === 'tach_in') {
        item.flight_total.value = item.tach_out.value - item.tach_in.value;
    }    
}

If total is needed on the View grid, than use similar approach as msaccess one for Actual Amount.
